# How to get size file with FileUploader SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I want to get size file with FileUploader SAPUI5. I try:

xml:

```
<u:FileUploader
    change="changeFileUploader"
    id="fileUploader"
    name="myFileUpload"
    uploadUrl="upload/"
    width="400px"
    tooltip="Upload your file to the local server"
    uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete"/>
```

controller:

```
changeFileUploader : function(oEvent){
    var oFileUploader = this.getView().byId("fileUploader").getValue();
    var item = oEvent.getParameter("fileSize");
    alert(item);
},
```

But when I alert "item", the value is "undefined", not the size file. How to fix this problem?

Regards,
Bobby

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getSize()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ca.ui.FileUpload.html#getSize) method

```
var oFileUploader  = this.getView().byId("fileUploader");
var oFileSize =  oFileUploader.getSize();
```

Comment: depricated since 1.26, the new FileUploader doesnt have this methode...